# cURL initialization and access to it after reloading page

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use cURL after page reload. First, I need to get question from other website, then i wanted to ask user about answer to this question and then send it using get / post to the same page(my page)
And after:
send the answer using cURL to another page. Unfortunately, I get the message:

> Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid cURL handle
>   resource

($ch variable is not visible after page reloading what can i do with it?)
My Code:

```
if(!isset($_GET['answer']))
{
$cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $question_url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$question = curl_exec($ch );
echo $question.
'<form name="input" method="get">
    Question: <input type="text" name="answer">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form> ';
} else
{
   $postFields['answer'] = $_GET['answer'];
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $answer_url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
   curl_exec ($ch);
}
```

I thought that I could initialize cURL in session, but it is not working too.

Answer (score 0):

See about putting your curl_init() outside your conditional. If the page is reloading there is a high likelihood that it's never being invoked, meaning your curl connection doesn't exist, hence the error.

```
$ch = curl_init();
if(!isset($_GET['answer']))
{
$cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
//removed
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $question_url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$question = curl_exec($ch );
echo $question.
'<form name="input" method="get">
    Question: <input type="text" name="answer">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form> ';
} else
{
   $postFields['answer'] = $_GET['answer'];
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $answer_url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
   curl_exec ($ch);
}
```

This way you know you'll always have that handle no matter which part of the conditional runs. Even though conditionals in PHP have no scope when it comes to variables defined within an if (that variable can be accessed outside the if), but if that if (too many ifs) never runs to begin with, the variable will never exist regardless of scope.

Comment: If i do that i don't get error in php, but i got message from the website "You don't have permission"
I think there is a problem with $ch
($ch in the first part of conition is not the same $ch that is in the second part of condition)

Comment: You don't have permission to do what? Looking at your code you seem to be posting something to some url, and I have no idea what that url is.